# Convertendo uma lista de listas de vetores em uma lista de matrizes - R

Tags: r, lista, matriz

Estou trabalhando em um modelo ambiental que retorna uma lista de vetores. Cada lista corresponde a um ponto no espaço, e cada vetor é uma série temporal de dados para diferentes variáveis. Estou tentando extrair cada vetor de cada lista para criar matrizes, uma para cada variável.

A estrutura que eu estou tentando converter parece com isso:

```
t <- list(list("r" = c(1,2,3), "e" = c(4,5,6), "t" = c(7,8,9)),
          list("r" = c(11,12,13), "e" = c(14,15,16), "t" = c(17,18,19)))
```

Eu quero que se torne isso:

```
t0 <- list("r" = do.call(rbind, list(c(1,2,3), c(11,12,13))),
           "e" = do.call(rbind, list(c(4,5,6), c(14,15,16))),
           "t" = do.call(rbind, list(c(7,8,9), c(17,18,19))))
```

Como eu poderia fazer essa conversão sem precisar especificar os nomes das colunas, mas mesmo assim mantendo-os para acessar usando o operador `$`?

Answer (score 3):

Se a estrutura de todos os elementos das listas é a mesma, i.e., possuem todos os mesmos nomes e comprimentos, pode-se colocá-los em um mesmo arranjo e depois separá-los pelo número de variáveis e de elementos em cada vetor. O processo não preserva os nomes, mas basta recuperá-los no final. Se roda seu modelo várias vezes, coloque tudo em uma função para facilitar:

```
arruma.lista <- function(lista) {
  n.var <- length(lista[[1]])  # número de variáveis:
  n.elmt <- length(lista[[1]][[1]])  # número de elementos em cada variável
  lista.a <- matrix(unlist(lista), ncol = length(lista))  # matriz geral
  lista.a <- split(lista.a, rep(seq(n.var), each = n.elmt))  # separa por variável
  lista.a <- lapply(lista.a, matrix, nrow = length(lista), byrow = TRUE)  # converte para matriz
  names(lista.a) <- names(lista[[1]])  # recupera os nomes
  return(lista.a)
}

t2 <- arruma.lista(t)

> t2$e
    [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    4    5    6
[2,]   14   15   16
```